# How can I display Images and Videos seamlessly with python on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, screen, hdmi

I have a Raspberry Pi which pulls images and Videos from a Database. Now I want to display the Images and Videos Fullscreen via HDMI with Python. I tried to use python-vlc, but when I displayed an Image and want to load the next one the Image disappears for a second and you can see the Console.

Do you have any Idea how I can display the Media seamlessly?

I work with Python3 and Raspbian Lite.

Answer (score 1):

Don't destroy the window after displaying one image.
An example code is:

```
img1=cv2.imread('image1.jpg')
cv2.imshow('window',img1)
cv2.waitKey(3000)   # display for 3 seconds
img2=cv2.imread('image2.jpg')
cv2.imshow('window',img2)
cv2.waitKey(3000)
```

and so on...